# Architecture to avoid creating repositories inside testable methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, architecture

Working on an MVVM application. Each ViewModel class has a constructor which accepts a Repository class so that it can be mocked out for unit testing.

The application is designed to be operated across several windows at once. So it contains a number "View" or "Open" style methods which create new ViewModels and place them into new windows. Because these are triggered via the UI, they are often inside existing ViewModels. For instance:

```
public void ViewQuote(Quote quote)
{
    if (quote.CreatedOn == null)
    {
        quote.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    NavigationHelper.NewWindow(this, new QuoteViewModel(quote, new Repository()));
}
```

Now, that flow control statement looks worth testing to ensure that quotes passed with a null CreatedOn date get assigned one. However, my test for this fails because although the parent ViewModel has a mocked Repository, the NewWindow method spins up a new ViewModel with a real-life Repository inside it. This then throws an error when it's used inside the constructor of that class.

There are two obvious options.

One is to pull out the date assignment into a stand-alone function to test. That'll work, but it seems too simplistic for its own function. Plus if I do it all over the application it risks creating too much fragmentation for easy readability.

The other is to somehow change the constructor code for ViewModels to not use the Repository directly. That might be an option here, but it's unlikely to be workable for every possible scenario.

Or is there a third way to design this better so I can pass a mocked Repository into the constructor of my new ViewModel?

Comment: You could introduce an `IRepositoryFactory`, or inject `IRepository` in the view.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. I'd rather not go back and change everything to work with dependency injection (although it might be worthwhile). I'm not entirely sure how a factory would help in this instance?

Comment: Then in your View classes, you inject an `IRepositoryFactory` with an `IRepository CreateRepository()` method, and in the code you show you do a call to the factory. When testing you inject a mock returning a mocked repository. Either way, the `new ...()` is what must be replaced to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Newing up services (or service-like objects such as repositories) is a design smell.** And the problems that you're experiencing are the consequence.

**In other words, you are lacking a clear and well-defined [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).**

### Solution: Use proper dependency injection

The only clean solution to this is to inject services through the constructor. Repositories usually have a shorter lifecycle than the application itself, so in this case you would inject a factory that is able to create the repository.

Note that clear dependency trees are good design, but using a DI framework such as [Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is only one technical solution to implement such a design. You can completely solve your problems and create a clean composition root without using a DI framework.

**So although this is probably a lot of work, you should redesign your application to have a clear composition root. Otherwise, you will run into small issues over and over again, especially in the testing area.**

Comment: Thanks. After spending a couple of hours looking into this, I'm really confused about how I can achieve this in WPF. I can create a container in the OnStartUp method and use it to get a ViewModel, but in MVVM I need to spin up new ViewModels outside OnStartUp?

Comment: It depends on how you use MVVM. The basic pattern is to have a view-model factory available (through dependency injection) wherever you need to instantiate view-models. Assign the instantiated child VM to a property of the parent VM. In the XAML, set the data context of the child view to the property in the parent VM. Then, use a data template for the child VM type so that WPF knows which view to render for the VM.

Comment: I am unable to find good examples right now. [This link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) shows a possible solution using ContentControl, even though the naming of the properties is horrible there. But it should give you a starting point. AND whatever you do, don't use a view model locator / service locator, or you'll be back to square one with testability...

Comment: Thanks. I was sufficiently bemused about this to create another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184434/adding-dependency-injection-to-an-mvvm-application?noredirect=1#comment56115568_34184434

Answer (score -1):

You could work around it by adding a `public Repository NewRepository` property, in your `ViewQuote` method change it to look like this:

```
public void ViewQuote(Quote quote)
{
    if (quote.CreatedOn == null)
    {
        quote.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }
    if(NewRepository == null) NewRepository = new Respository();
    NavigationHelper.NewWindow(this, new QuoteViewModel(quote, NewRepository));
}
```

Then in your mock, just ensure that the public `NewRepository` property is assigned to before the test is run on that bit of code.

Not very elegant, but it would require the least amount of changing in my opinion.